# Is this a metric on the Grassmannian Manifold?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, matrices, determinants, grassmannians

Let $m>n$ and consider the Set
$$S_{m,n}=\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}\lvert A^TA=I_n \}.$$
Does the function $d\colon S_{m,n} \times S_{m,n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$d(A,B)=\sqrt{1-\det(A^TB)}$$
define a pseudometric on $S_{m,n}$? (A pseudometric satisfies all conditions of a metric except that two elements can also have distance zero.) 
Consider the equivalence relation $A \sim B$ if there exist an orthogonal $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $A=BQ$. The set $S_{m,n}$ together with the equivalence relation can be identified with the grassmannian manifold $Gr(n,\mathbb{R}^m)$. Does $d$ define a metric on $Gr(n,\mathbb{R}^m)$? This question interests me because im trying to approximate (interpolate) functions which take values in the grassmanian manifold and the above metric would open up a possibility for approximating such functions.
The difficult part is the triangle-inequality, i.e. for all $A,B,C \in S_{m,n}$ we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{1-\det(A^TC)}\leq \sqrt{1-\det(A^TB)}+\sqrt{1-\det(B^TC)}.$$

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It is obvious that when n=1.

Comment: Minor observation: You are building a metric on the oriented Grassmannian, not the Grassmannian. If $S$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix with determinant $-1$, then $A$ and $AS$ represent the same point of the Grassmannian, but $\det(A^T (AS)) = \det(S) = -1$, so your formula gives $\sqrt{2}$, not $0$.

Comment: @David: to get a distance function for the grassmanian one has to add an absolute value, i.e. $$d(A,B)=\sqrt{1-|\det(A^TB)|}.$$

Comment: @user35593: but to show this to be a metric (with the abs) value, requires slightly more work than just an invocation of CB....

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Can you please give a reference, why this is a correct distance for oriented Grassmannian? Thanks!

Comment: @user27493 Whenever you have a set $X$ with a pseudometric $d$, you can define an equivalence relation on $X$ by $x \sim y$ iff $d(x,y)=0$. Then $d$ is a metric on the set of equivalence classes of $\sim$. Let $X$ be the set of $m \times n$ matrices obeying $A^T A = \mathrm{Id}_n$ or, in other words, $n$-tuples of orthonormal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$, equipped with the above pseudo-metric. What are the equivalence classes of $\sim$ or, in other words, when is $d(A,B)=0$? (continued)

Comment: The answer is if and only if $A=BQ$ for $Q \in SO(n)$. As I note above, if $A = BQ$ with $Q$ an orthogonal matrix of determinant $-1$, then $d(A,B) = \sqrt{2}$, not $0$. In other words, $d(A,B)=0$ if the columns of $A$ and $B$ are orthonormal bases for the same $n$-plane WITH THE SAME ORIENTATION. So $X/\sim$ is the set of oriented $n$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT** Actually, Cauchy-Binet suffices as the OP notices in the comments. I'll leave my overkill proof here for your amusement.

---

The proof below appeals to a famous result of Schoenberg (I've simplified the statement a bit), and basic linear algebra.

> **Schoenberg's theorem** (see e.g., [Prop. 3.2, 1]).  Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $\psi: X \times X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be positive definite kernel. Then, there exists an RKHS $H$ and a map $\varphi : X \to H$ such that
>   \begin{equation*}
>   \|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)\|_H^2 = \frac{1}{2}[\psi(x,x)+\psi(y,y)] - \psi(x,y).
> \end{equation*}

We show that the function $\psi(A,B) = \det(A^TB)$ is positive definite, which as a result of Schoenberg's theorem shows that
\begin{equation*}
  1-\det(A^TB) = \|\varphi(A)-\varphi(B)\|_H^2,
\end{equation*}
from which the triangle inequality is immediate.

To prove the positive definiteness of $\psi$, we show that it is an inner-product by invoking the [Cauchy-Binet formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) (using Wikipedia's notation, except that for us $A$ is $m \times n$):
\begin{equation*}
  \det(A^TB) = \sum_{S \in \binom{[m]}{n}} \det(A^T_{[n],S})\det(B_{S,[n]}) = \sum_{S \in \binom{[m]}{n}} \det(A_{S,[n]})\det(B_{S,[n]}) = \langle \phi(A), \phi(B)\rangle.
\end{equation*}

**[1]**  C. Berg, J. P. R. Christensen, and P. Ressel. *Harmonic Analysis on Semigroups: Theory of Positive Definite and Related Functions*, Springer GTM 100, 1984.

Comment: After seeing the Cauchy-Binet formula I found a proof without Schoenberg' theorem: Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^{\binom{m}{n}}$ be definded by terms from the Cauchy-Binet formula, i.e. $\det(A_{S,[n]})$. Then $\|a\|_2^2=\|b\|_2^2=\|c\|_2^2=1$. The triangle inequality for $\mathbb{R}^{\binom{m}{n}}$ gives $$\sqrt{\langle a-c,a-c \rangle}\leq \sqrt{\langle a-b,a-b \rangle}+\sqrt{\langle b-c,b-c \rangle}$$
which boils down to the desired inequality.

Comment: That is exactly the way to go! so Cauchy-Binet suffices, very nice, I should have thought about the problem a bit before shooting off my answer!

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is true, this inequality has interesting geometry.
However it is not an answer:

Let us see m>n=1.
take inner  product $(a,b)=\cos \gamma, (b,c)=\cos \alpha, (a,c)=\cos b$,
by Euclidean geometry it is obvious $\alpha+\gamma>\beta$

To prove :
$$\sqrt{1-\det(A^TC)}\leq \sqrt{1-\det(A^TB)}+\sqrt{1-\det(B^TC)}.$$

$$\sqrt{1-\det(A^TB)}+\sqrt{1-\det(B^TC)}\geq \sqrt{2-\det(A^TB)-det(B^{T}C)}.$$

It is suffices to prove:
$$2-\det(A^TB)-det(B^{T}C)\geq 1-det(A^TC)$$.

For n=1, it is equivalent to prove the following:
$$\sin^{2}(\frac{\beta}{2})\leq \sin^{2}(\frac{\alpha}{2})+\sin^{2}(\frac{\gamma}{2})$$

Notice the fact that $\alpha+\gamma>\beta$, this is obvious.

When $n\geq 2$, I think it is better to consider the n-dimension subspace in $R^{m}$, 
$\det(A^TB)$ is just cosin angel of two subspaces.

Comment: The statement with the sinuses is wrong for e.g. $\alpha=\gamma=44^{\circ}$ and $\beta=90^{\circ}$. The squareroot is important. However thanks for your contribution. For the case $n\geq 2$ how do you define an angle between two subspaces?

Comment: Just consider a triangular pyramidal with three line a,b,c. the corresponded angle $$\alpha,\beta,\gamma$$, we will have:$$\alpha+\beta>\gamma$$, and $$\alpha+\gamma>\beta$$, and $$\beta+\alpha>\gamma$$. I f we did not use the simple inequality $$\sqrt{x+y}\leq \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$, we need to prove $$\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}\leq \sin\frac{\beta}{2}+\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}$$