# Does this cross-product norm inequality hold?

Tags: linear-algebra

I asked this [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471675/does-this-cross-product-norm-inequality-hold) over a month ago, but the one answer I got doesn't seem to work.

Let $\times$ denote the cross-product. $\;$ Is it the case that

> For all unit vectors $\:\mathbf{x}\hspace{.01 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{-0.03 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}\mathbf{z}\:$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$, $\;\;\;\; \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{z}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \:\: \leq \:\: \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \hspace{.02 in}+\hspace{.02 in}\left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{y} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{z}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \;\;\;\;\;$.

?

(If yes, then $\;\;\; \langle [\mathbf{x}]\hspace{.01 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}[\hspace{.02 in}\mathbf{y}] \rangle \: \mapsto \: \left|\left|\hspace{.03 in}\mathbf{x} \hspace{-0.03 in}\times \hspace{-0.03 in}\mathbf{y}\hspace{.02 in}\right|\right| \;\;\;$ defines a nice metric on the projective plane.)

Comment: What about the following: Fix $x$ and $z$ and consider the right hand side as a function of $y$; a map $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. If we can show that its minimum is larger than the constant on the right, we're done. It's easy to see that the gradient (which for simplicity we can consider to be a vector field using the usual metric on $S^2$) of $y \to || x \times y ||$ is zero at the poles ($\pm x$) and on the equator, and everywhere else points towards the equator. We can assume the vectors $x$ and $z$ are at an angle bigger than $0$ and less than $\pi/2$ (trivial cases)...

Comment: ... Adding the gradient vector fields of $y \to ||x \times y||$ and $y \to ||y \times z||$ together, it is easy to see that the sum is zero at exactly four points: there are maxima where the two 'equators' meet, and minima at the points equidistant from $x$ and $z$ on the great circle containing them. The total function has the same value at each, so just look at the point in between $x$ and $z$. The result follows because $sin 2\theta < 2sin \theta$. A picture would help.

Comment: I seem to have missed the editing window. It should read "the constant on the _left_". Also, the situation that $x$ and $z$ are orthogonal is not trivial, but does fit in with the rest of what I said.

Comment: wow, the $\LaTeX$ markup of this looks crazy! was it generated by machine?

Comment: No, although it would be nice if there was a program to automatically put in $\hspace{1.76 in}$ better spacing than LaTeX uses on its own. $\:$

Comment: Since $x \times y$ is the Hodge dual of $x \wedge y$ one should indeed expect that the norm of $x \times y$ would induce a norm on the projective plane.

Comment: For completeness, I believe I missed a couple of critical points in my reasoning above. However, I think these can be dealt with too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The alleged inequality is true.

Using the definition of the [(vector) cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product), for unit vectors $x, y \in R^3$ the original claim boils down to showing that 
\begin{equation*}
  d(x,y) = \sin(\cos^{-1}(x^Ty))
\end{equation*}
is a distance. But it turns out that $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is actually is a distance on unit vectors in $R^n$.

Showing the above function to be a distance is equivalent to showing that
\begin{equation*}
  \sqrt{1 - (x^Ty)^2}
\end{equation*}
is a distance over the set of unit vectors in $R^n$. But this is a known result of [Wang and Zhang](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2974909), *"A trace inequality for unitary matrices"*, AMM, 1994, pp. 453-455.

*EDIT:* Also worth comparing with the recent determinant based distance described [in this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141483/is-this-a-metric-on-the-grassmannian-manifold/141535#141535) (which suggests that actually after suitable normalization, other symmetric matrix functions should also generate distances, e.g., $d(X,Y) := [1-\text{trace}(\wedge^k(X^TY))]^{1/2}$.

Comment: What is your vector product on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Ok, fixed unfortunate wording (probably the vector product on $R^n$ will be somehow related to $x \wedge y$, but I'm not using that); the claim is true as written, and yields the $R^3$ case as a special case.

Comment: Should "vector product" be replaced with "cross product"? $\:$ If no, what do you mean by that? $\hspace{.78 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Yes, by "vector product" I mean the "cross product" in your original question. Am editing the answer once more to avoid confusion.

Comment: d(.,.) is not a distance since d(x,y)=0 does not imply that x=y (think about the case x=-y). It is a distance only over the open hemisphere.