# Does the product of principal sines between subspaces satisfy the triangle inequalilty?

Tags: linear-algebra

As we know that the volume of a matrix $X$ is defined as $\sqrt{\det(X^TX)}$, if we consider the volume of two matrices $X$ and $Y$, with $X,Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times d},d<N,\dim(X)=\dim(Y)=d$, then the volume of $[X,Y]$ is $\sqrt{\det([X,Y]^T[X,Y])}$, where $[X,Y]$ means juxtaposition of $X$ and $Y$.
My question is, As we know that the product of principal sines between two disjoint subspaces spanned by matrices $X$ and $Y$ has a relation with volume:
$vol([X,Y])=vol(X)\cdot vol(Y)\cdot \prod_i^d \sin \theta_i(X,Y)$,
with $\prod_i^d \sin \theta_i(X,Y)$ the product of principal sines between $X$ and $Y$,
Does this product of principal sines $\prod_i^d \sin \theta_i(X,Y)$ satisfy the triangle inequality?
In another word, if we have $X,Y,Z \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times d}, \dim(X)=\dim(Y)=\dim(Z)=d$, will this relationship
$\prod_i^d \sin \theta_i([X,Y]) \leq \prod_i^d \sin \theta_i([X,Z]) + \prod_i^d \sin \theta_i([Z,Y])$
hold?
As we know that this inequality holds for 1-dimensional scenarios, where $vol(x)=\|x\|_2$, and $vol([x,y])=\|x\|\|y\|\cdot sin\theta(x,y)$, we can have $\sin \theta(x,y) \leq \sin \theta(x,z) + \sin \theta(z,y)$.
Can it hold for multi-dimensional scenarios as above?

Comment: I doubt it. But you may nevertheless be interested in: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144411/does-this-cross-product-norm-inequality-hold/144420#144420

Comment: Thank you! The question raised in your link just coincided with the 1-dimensional scenario in my question, where $vol([x,y])=\|x \times y\|$, I am just curious that will this relation hold for more dimensions?

Comment: If you read my answer there, including links to other questions, you'll see that higher dimensions are also covered, though not in the exact form that you mention...

Comment: I have read your answer that the triangle inequality hold for this version of distance:$d(X,Y)=\sqrt{1-\det(X^TY)}=\sqrt{1-\prod_i^d \cos^2\theta_i(X,Y)}$. But I'm still curious when it comes to the sines of principal angles $d(X,Y) = \prod_i^d\sin\theta_i(X,Y)$, does this triangle inequality still hold?

Comment: $[X,Y]$ is not a commutator here, isn't it? I am sure that it is not but these notations are REALLY confusing. I will give a counterexample because I can't resist these notations. Of course the triangle inequality doesn't hold for the ""commutator" volumes. We can take $X,Y,Z$ -- the generators of Heisenberg group. $[X,Z]=[Y,Z]=0$ but $[X,Y]=Z \neq 0$ so the left-hand side ofthe inequality is positive and the right-hand side is zero. Consider it more like a facetious comment.

Comment: I guess $[X,Y]$ means juxtaposition. But of course it must be explained. My counterexample with juxtaposition would be $X=(1,0,0)$, $Y=(0,1,0)$, $Z=(0,0,1/10)$.

Comment: So sorry for my ambiguous notation, It's my fault, $[X,Y]$ means juxtaposition, where $X$ and $Y$ are put together to get a $N \times 2d$ matrix. And I forgot the constraints that $vol(X)=vol(Y)=vol(Z)=1$, which means only the principal angles $\prod_i^d\sin\theta_i(X,Y)$ are concerned.

Comment: Not a direct answer but might I suggest that the circle of ideas around the Brunn-Minkowski inequality could be of interest? There is a fairly comprehensive Wikipedia article about it.

Comment: It seems that the juxtaposition leads to a quantity that is not even symmetric, leave alone a distance...something I'm missing perhaps...