# Is the product of sine principal angles a semi-metric on Grassmannian?

Tags: grassmannians

Let's say we have two $d$ dimensional subspaces with principal angles $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_d$. Then, if $U,V$ are the orthonormal bases for these two subspaces, the singular values of $U'V$ are $\cos\theta_1,\dots,\cos\theta_d$. Now we define 
$$D(U,V) = \sqrt{\det(I-U'VV'U)}= \prod_{i=1}^d \sin\theta_i$$
My question is: is the above defined $D(U,V)$ a semi-metric? Essentially, I am asking, does the triangle inequality hold here, i.e., $D(U,W)\leq D(U,V)+D(V,W)$?

There is a similar post:
[Does the product of principal sines between subspaces satisfy the triangle inequalilty?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149200/does-the-product-of-principal-sines-between-subspaces-satisfy-the-triangle-inequ)

But no explicit answer was given there.

Comment: Say $U'U=I_d$ and $V'V=I_d$, then unless I'm completely overseeing something obvious, it is pretty easy to find counterexamples to the triangle inequality.

Comment: Thanks! But do you have specific counterexamples when the subspaces spanned by U,W and V are pairwisely disjoint? @Suvrit