# Canonical Metric on Grassmann Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds

I was curious and quite clueless as to how we can equip the Grassmann Manifold with a canonical metric - I have yet to find anything upon this subject.

Comment: The Grassmanian is a homogeneous space for the orthogonal group (unitary group in the complex case) and hence inherits a natural metric.

Comment: If you want an explicit formula, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141483/is-this-a-metric-on-the-grassmannian-manifold

Comment: See http://www.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/systems/Publi/Grass_geom.pdf, for the Grassmann manifold of $p$-planes in $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Comment: The space $\mathrm{Gr}(p,V)$ of $p$-dimensional subspaces in a vector space $V$ does *not* have a nontrivial canonical metric.  There is no Riemannian metric on this space that is invariant under the natural action of $\mathrm{Aut}(V)=\mathrm{GL}(V)$.  Upon fixing an additional structure on $V$, namely, a positive definite inner product $q$, there is a Riemannian metric on this space that is invariant under the natural action of $\mathrm{Aut}(V,q)=\mathrm{O}(q)$, unique up to a constant multiple.  This multiple can be uniquely determined by specifying the total volume or diameter, for example.

Comment: @PaulSiegel , Aaron asked canonical metric not natural metric, ;) . See my answer

Comment: @RobertBryant Is there an official notion of a "canonical metric"? Though no metric is invariant under $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$, all metrics produced by some of the extra choices you name give isometric Riemannian manifolds in the end. In my understanding, this is as canonical as one can ever get (compare "Jordan canonical form" etc).

Comment: @SebastianGoette:  It's a question of terminology, I suppose, and I am not sure what office is qualified to rule on the 'official' notions. `Canonical' in mathematical English has several different meanings; I usually use 'canonical' to mean 'invariantly defined', and when there is more than one 'natural' candidate, I prefer not to call any of them canonical. (By the way, I learned to call it 'Jordan normal form', not 'Jordan canonical form', which, although I see it in various places, always looks a little odd to me, since it's not clear to me just what is canonical about Jordan normal form.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since Grassmannian $Gr(n,m)=SO(n+m)/SO(n)\times SO(m)$ is a homogeneous manifold,
you can take any Riemannian metric, and average with $SO(n+m)$-action. Then you show that an $SO(n+m)$-invariant metric is unique up to a constant. This is easy, because the tangent space $T_VGr(n,m)$ (tangent space to a plane $V\subset W$)
is $Hom(V,V^\bot)$, and your metric must be $SO(V)\times SO(V^\bot)$-invariant.
Such a metric is unique (up to a constant multiplier), which follows, e.g., from Schur's lemma.

Comment: he asking canonical metric,

Comment: @HassanJolany This metric is actually symmetric and unique up to a constant multiple, as stated above. Any normalisation you wish to choose makes it canonical.

Comment: what is the your definition about canonical metric,?

Comment: @HassanJolany "Canonical" as I understand means "produced by a process involving no additional choices". Since the manifolds here are (probably) real, there is no chance of mistaking "canonical" with something related to a "canonical" bundle or else. But these metrics are symmetric of compact type, so they have many nice properties (Einstein, parallel curvature tensor, hence the sectional curvature has the same structure everywhere, nonnegative curvature operator, so all harmonic differential forms are parallel etc.). What else would you ask for?

Comment: Have you seen this paper? http://jgrivaux.perso.math.cnrs.fr/articles/Tian.pdf In fact we use alpha invariant of Tian to get Kahler Eiinstein metric, when the first Chern class is positive , I am still woundring if you show me it is Kahler Einstein

Comment: To repeat what Sebastian already said, the question refers to Grassmannians, which most of us would interpret as real Grassmannians, i.e., $G(n,k) = $ the space of $k$-linear subspaces in an $n$-dimensional real vector space. In general there is no complex structure on such a space, for example if the Grassmannian is odd-dimensional. However, it is a homogeneous space, and the standard meaning of a "canonical metric" on a homogeneous space is one that is invariant under the group action.

Comment: @HassanJolany The main point of the paper you mention is the computation of the Tian invariant. Did you find anything on the metric in Besse? To the best of my knowledge, the Kähler-Einstein property for irreducible Hermitian symmetric spaces has been known long before. It follows from curvature computations using the Lie brackets of the Lie groups involved.

Comment: I didn't know the book of Besse, I just checked it. It seems it had long history and I didn't know anything about it.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, $Gr(n,m)$ with its canonical metric induced from an Euclidean structure is one of the few spaces where you can write down solutions of the geodesic equations explicitly by a formula and write down a formula for the geodesic distance. See the following paper for this

- MR1856419 Neretin, Yurii A. On Jordan angles and the triangle inequality in Grassmann manifolds. Geom. Dedicata 86 (2001), no. 1-3, 81–92.

Comment: So is there any exception to what Yurii has shown? Should any invariant metric on the grassmannian look like a symmetric norm function of Jordan angles?

Comment: Since it is an irreducible symmetric space of compact type, there is not a lot of choice: any invariant metric is a constant multiple of this one.

Comment: Great!...do you mind providing a reference? i.e. uniqueness of invariant Finsler metric...I'm kinda slow...I am an engineer...

Comment: Misha Verbitsky's answer gives you a proof in 3 lines. Helgason: "Differential Geometry, Symmetric Spaces, and Lie groups" is a standard reference, but by far too much for this simple question. As a Finsler metric it is not unique: any power of the Riemannian norm is an invariant Finsler metric.

Comment: Oh, by the way, is it possible to characterize all invariant Finsler metrics in some way?

Comment: What I said about Finsler was wrong, I forgot that they have to be positive homogeneous. Now my guess is that it is unique (up to a positive constant) and that it is Riemannian. That should follow from invariant theory applied to positively homogeneous continuous functions, in the setting of Verbitzky's answer.

Comment: What if I drop the homogeneity condition? i.e. if I talk about invariant metric, but not invariant Finsler metric? Is it possible to characterize such metrics then?

Answer (score 5):

A nice geometric way of endowing a Grassmann manifold with a metric (understood here as a *distance*, and not directly as a *Riemannian metric*) is to use the [Hausdorff distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) for subsets of the round sphere.

Consider $V$ a real vector space of dimension $n$ endowed with an inner product, and let $Gr_k(V)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes on $V$. Let $x,y\in Gr_k(V)$, and denote by $S_x$ and $S_y$ the subspheres of the unit sphere $S_V=\{v\in V:\|v\|=1\}$ defined by intersecting it with the subspaces $x$ and $y$ respectively. Then $S_x,S_y\subset S_V$ are closed subsets and the distance between $x,y\in Gr_k(V)$ can be defined as the Hausdorff distance between these sets:
$$dist(x,y)=dist_H(S_x,S_y).$$

Note that this distance **does not coincide** with the symmetric space distance on $Gr_k(V)=SO(n)/SO(k)SO(n-k)$. As explained in the paper of Neretin in Michor's answer, the symmetric space distance is computed in terms of the [*principal angles*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_angles) between two subspaces (namely, it is the square root of the sum of the squares of these angles); while the above distance defined in terms of the Hausdorff distance of closed sets in the unit sphere measures exactly the largest principal angle between subspaces, ignoring all the other smaller principal angles.